# Sending email using Gmail gives a time out error

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, timeoutexception

We are testing some code to send email messages using Gmail from a form, but get a time out error.

Can you tell us what is missing from this code to get the email message sent?

```
    Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()

        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("ouremail@gmail.com", "MyPasswordGoesHere")
        SmtpServer.Port = 465
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        mail.From = New MailAddress("ouremail@gmail.com")
        mail.To.Add("ouremail@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
        mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL"

        SmtpServer.Send(mail)

        MsgBox("mail sent")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Update:
Code change using MailBee. This is how we are doing emails to all the customers:

```
    Dim strSqlStatement As String = "Select CustomerName, Email " & _
                               "From Customers " & _
                              "Where Email Is Not Null"
    If IsConnected() Then

        ' Set up the sql command and lookup the parent.
        '----------------------------------------------
        Using objSqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSqlStatement, ObjConnection)

            With objSqlCommand

                ' Open the SqlConnection before executing the query.
                '---------------------------------------------------
                Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

                ObjConnection.Open()

                Dim objDataReader As SqlDataReader = .ExecuteReader()

                ' Go through all the customers and send out the promotion emails.
                '----------------------------------------------------------------
                If objDataReader.HasRows Then

                    MailBee.Global.LicenseKey = "My license key goes here."

                    Dim objSMTP As New Smtp
                    Dim server As New SmtpServer(TextBoxSMTPServer.Text, TextBoxUserName.Text, TextBoxPassword.Text)

                    'SmtpServer.Host = TextBoxSMTPServer.Text
                    'SmtpServer.Port = TextBoxPort.Text
                    'SmtpServer.Timeout = 100

                    'If TextBoxUseSSL.Text = "Yes" Then
                    '    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
                    'Else
                    '    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = False
                    'End If

                    'If TextBoxUseDefaultCredentials.Text = "Yes" Then
                    '    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                    'Else
                    '    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                    'End If

                    'SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(TextBoxUserName.Text, TextBoxPassword.Text)


                    objSMTP.SmtpServers.Clear()
                    objSMTP.SmtpServers.Add(server)

                    While objDataReader.Read()
                        If objDataReader("Email").ToString <> "" Then

                            objSMTP.Message.From.AsString = TextBoxEmailFrom.Text
                            objSMTP.Message.To.AsString = objDataReader("Email").ToString
                            objSMTP.Message.Subject = "Promotion: " & TextBoxID.Text
                            objSMTP.Message.BodyPlainText = "Dear " & objDataReader("CustomerName") & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & TextBoxPromotionBodyText.Text

                            Try
                                objSMTP.Send()

                            Catch exBadPassword As MailBeeSmtpLoginBadCredentialsException
                                MsgBox("The login name or password is not correct.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Email")
                                blnThereWereErrors = True

                            Catch exBadFromAddress As MailBeeSmtpRefusedSenderException
                                MsgBox("The sender email must be the same as the user's email address.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Email")
                                blnThereWereErrors = True

                            Catch ex As Exception
                                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                                blnThereWereErrors = True
                            End Try
                        End If

                        If blnThereWereErrors Then
                            Exit While
                        End If
                    End While

                    If blnThereWereErrors = False Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Mass emailing has completed." & vbCrLf, _
                                "Email Message.", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    End If
                End If

                objDataReader.Close()
                ObjConnection.Close()

                Cursor = Cursors.Default
            End With ' objSqlCommand
        End Using ' objSqlCommand
```

Comment: Code looks good. Maybe it is a UAC problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it still times out.

Comment: matter a fact try to connect via command line telnet smtp.gmail.com 465, If you can connect than try setting UseDefaultCredentials = False

Comment: Thanks kcbeard for the reply. I tried o smtp.gmail.com 465 in telnet and it seems to get stuck showing: connecting to smtp.gmail.com... and just showing a flashing cursor then it sais: Connection to host lost. I was able to connect to towel.blinkenlights.nl and that worked. Not sure why there is a problem with gmail. I use gmail in my email client software all the time without any problems. Is there an open source control I can use in my form that works with email?

Comment: I was able to get it working by using another email server. Not sure why there's a problem with Gmail.

Comment: I am guessing its probably not Google, It is strange that happened. What kind of environment are you working in. Do you guys have a firewall, or hard wall of some sorts?

Comment: I'm working in a Parallels virtual machine running Windows7 on a Mac. I used bluebottle.com as the email server at that works perfectly. At least I know the code works.

Comment: We tried using MailBee and all email problems disappeared. Not sure why but I think it cycles through port numbers and finds the best one to use. I'm updating the code in the post to show MailBee in use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using a different port number. You cannot use port 465 with `System.Net.Mail` as it only supports "Explicit SSL". Have a look at [this page](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/5.3.aspx) for more info on this.

Gmail will accept port 25 or 587 when sending mail via VB.NET but times out using port 465.

Also make sure you have `UseDefaultCredentials = False`

Also have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail) on how to send mail using GMail in C# it might give you some more clue.

Comment: Yes i had the same problem when using port 465. I fixed it by using 587

Answer (score -2):

I had similar problem, in my case I just forgot to specify the protocol, so instead of `smtp.gmail.com` I had to put `ssl://smtp.gmail.com`.