# System.Net.Mail timing out on send

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, system.net.mail, system.web.mail

I have some older code that works fine for sending emails, but visual studio tells me that the code is obsolete and I should change it over to `Net.Mail` from `Web.Mail`. I have rewritten most of it, but I have a few questions.

Here is the original, working code:

```
public void Send(string from, string to, string subject, string body, bool isHtml, string[] attachments)
{

    var mailMessage = new MailMessage

    {
        From = from,
        To = to,
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        BodyFormat = isHtml ? MailFormat.Html : MailFormat.Text
    };


    // Add attachments
    if (attachments != null)
    {
        foreach (var t in attachments)
        {
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(t));
        }
    }
    mailMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", 1);
    mailMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", _accountName);
    mailMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", _password);
    mailMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", _port.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
    mailMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", true);

    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = _smtp;
    SmtpMail.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

And here is the rewritten portion (well, sort of):

```
public void Send2(string from, string to, string subject, string body, bool isHtml, string[] attachments)
{
var fromObj = new MailAddress(from);
var toObj = new MailAddress(to);


var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
                      {
                          From = fromObj,
                          Subject = subject,
                          Body = body,
                          IsBodyHtml = isHtml,
                      };

mailMessage.To.Add(toObj);

if (attachments != null)
{
    foreach(var t in attachments)
    {
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(t));
    }
}

var smtp = new SmtpClient(_smtp) {Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_accountName, _password), Port = _port, EnableSsl = true};
smtp.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

In case you were wondering, I have `_port` and `_smtp` set higher up in the code, 465 and smtp.gmail.com respectively.

So it seems to work, but then gets down to the sending part and spits out one of these:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
```

Is there something I am missing, like from the `Fields` in the original code, that is causing it to timeout?

Thanks!

## SOLUTION

Thanks to [DavidH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2420979/davidh)'s point in the right direction, the port needs to be changed from **465** to **587** (or 25; I am using the former with no problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little Google goes a long way. Check this answer for your cure - you're using the wrong port:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11244548/2420979

Comment: Must have not used the right search terms...I promise I did look before posting! Thank you.